# Can drop database as user but cannot drop schema within database

Tags: postgresql

I have a database, `mydb` with a schema called `hdb_catalog`. I'm connected to the db cluster as the user `postgres`. I can drop the database `mydb` with `drop database;`. However, when I try to drop the schema with `DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS hdb_catalog CASCADE` I get the following error:

```
error: must be owner of schema hdb_catalog
```

Both of these users belong to the same `rds_superuser` group:

```
postgres=> \du
                                                               List of roles
    Role name    |                         Attributes                         |                          Member of
-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 admin           | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              |
 datadog         | Cannot login                                               | {}
 postgres        | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              |
 rds_ad          | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_iam         | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_password    | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_replication | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_superuser   | Cannot login                                               | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend,rds_replication,rds_password}
 rdsadmin        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS+| {}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              |
 rdsrepladmin    | No inheritance, Cannot login, Replication                  | {}
 rdstopmgr       | Password valid until infinity                              | {pg_monitor}
 root            | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              |
```

And the schema itself is owned by the `root` user (below is what I see when checking the DDL with intellij)

```
-- auto-generated definition
create schema hdb_catalog;

alter schema hdb_catalog owner to root;
```

How can I drop this schema as the postgres user which is part of the `rds_superuser` group?

Comment: You cannot. Just becase you own database doesn't mean you own schema inside it. It is as simple as that.

Comment: Are there any workarounds you'd recommend besides connecting as the `root` user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out just running `alter schema hdb_catalog owner to postgres` made it possible for the `postgres` user to drop the schema.

Comment: Yeah, but now `root` doesn't have access to it. The proper solution is to grant ownership to some role X and make both postgres and root members of that role X.

Comment: good point. thankfully I'm writing some automation and after dropping the schema I can recreate with ownership by `root`.